# Is it possible to create interface referring to itself type with [key: string] and it own props?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

Want to define interface like this, to create nested paths, is it possible to define interface like this?

```
interface IPath {
    path: string;
    name: string;

    [key: Exclude<string, 'path' | 'name'>]: IPath
}
```

this approach not work, there is error: *Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'IPath'.ts(2411)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **might** be able to do it by constructing a massively-complicated string literal key type that allowed strings that weren't `"path"` or `"name"`, but it would be very complicated (and probably slow to compile) even if it's possible.

Instead, either use a simpler string literal key type via a prefix (or suffix, or some other simple pattern that doesn't match `"path"` or `"name"`) on children like this, which is fairly similar to what you had, just slightly less open:

```typescript
type IPath = {
    path: string;
    name: string;
    [key: `child${string}`]: IPath;
};

const example: IPath = {
    path: "/something",
    name: "something",
    childX: {
        path: "/something/else",
        name: "something-else",
    },
    childY: {
        path: "/some/third/thing",
        name: "some third thing",
    },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgCgQ2ACygXigbwFBT1MJZALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbl31oQFsJSKaHn8oAbQDWEEKQAGAY2TUANgBMAJJh516AXwkBdUvCLMNzbFID2tClAgAPDmDldYiFOiws8hFKQBEAejKmnCjq3gA07lBsnD4BQbIMYREy8goAGqQ4AgKeJFB+sRDBDL4QcmQQiVmsHI7eBUX0ALSl5ZX4GuECyYoAmhkR2UQ+-oEQvsGUCuPx9G1VUbUFUBMKyzNzUB3YRkA)

...or use a property that's an array of children instead — this is the approach I'd take:

```typescript
interface IPath {
    path: string;
    name: string;
    children?: IPath[];
}

const example: IPath = {
    path: "/something",
    name: "something",
    children: [
        {
            path: "/something/else",
            name: "something-else",
        },
        {
            path: "/some/third/thing",
            name: "some third thing",
        },
    ],
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU5gBbIN4BQyxyADltgFzIDOYUoA5gNxEkhwC2E1dDILNsQTZgAGwAmUCCAD81DBQDaAXVYBfAgQQB7EHWQQAHl1JieaTDmQBefELIVqAIgD0NHdxxNnAGgcc3C4eXqICfg4i4lIy1EoOJPaJySTkOC7unhDeAq4QYjQQESkpgRbOIdlhjAC0+YXFJer+JUmtqU7IbpWu3lASvdWN7chlwVnIfRKTQy1Nc8Qq-urMQA)

Comment: solution with children looks nice, thanks for advice